# Can (or should) I use one view for multiple View Controls

Tags: xpages

In traditional Notes programming it was a best practice to use hidden views for things like DbLookups and non-hidden views for user facing views. This way you wouldn't get a request for a user to add a field to a view and break your lookups. Keep presentation separated form logic.

I still follow this in Xpages. But I was wondering if we can (or should) reuse hidden views that are used for data sources for more than one presentation view. In other words should there be a one to one correspondence between a view and a view type control. Are there limitations to having a many to one relationship?

Answer (score 3):

I think that in the XPages world...  assuming it's 100% an XPages app there's much less need for using Views as "presentation".  Since you can change things in your view and repeat controls for the presentation.

So you might end up having 1 view with many more fields then you need but that feeds multiple view controls and you're just showing the columns of interest etc.  The iffy part is if you're going to use the view control for sorting columns and all that.  I don't actually use the view control much.  I find it too limiting.  I prefer repeat controls.

So to answer you're question I think you absolutely should reuse views as many times as you want.  From a performance perspective the less views the better typically I think.

These days I do less with views overall.  I make Java Objects to represent my document.  So I'll use some views to find the correct documents and then push them into java objects.  Then in Java I'll use code to sort things different ways and send that back out to a repeat control.  Works very well and that lets me cut down on views.  BUT if you're doing this with 3,000+ documents...  there can be some delays for the initial injection so in some situations I might have to get back to actually touching the views just to get better performance.

Comment: +1 to David's comment about using repeats.  I took this a step further recently and created one repeat control that was used to display several views with the desired view/column info being stored in config docs.  This approach makes it easier to make view changes without always touching the design.  It also opens the door for easily allowing users to select which columns they want to see and storing those preferences in a separate config doc.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to maintain a one-to-one relationship between View design elements and View panel controls in an XPages application, and IMHO you shouldn't.

Consider a traditional Notes client application with only one Form design element and many, many View design elements.  When your main/only presentation tools are the Form and the View elements you tend to get a lot of Views to meet the various presentation requirements of the application.  Of course each added View will spawn an Index, increasing the size and decreasing performance in the application.

One great feature of XPages is the separation of the data and the presentation layer.  This allows you to reuse the same Domino View data source on several XPages with different presentation requirements -- each XPage displaying a different set of columns or uses a different iterator control to display the view data (xp:viewPanel, xp:repeat, xp:dataTable, xe:dataView, xe:dynamicViewPanel, or xe:djxDataGrid).

When I'm developing a new XPages application with no traditional Notes client access I find that I tend to create fewer, flatter, and often wider views (i.e. more columns).

I'm getting wider views with more columns because its more efficient to return column values then field values in the underlying document.  All of the iterator controls have a var variable to address the entries in the Domino View data source, even xe:djxDataGrid via its REST Service.  When using a Domino View data source I tend to set var="viewEntry" to reflect its NotesXspViewEntry type.

So, when there is no column for the field values I need to return (say  to a Computed Field in a View Column or in another facet of an iterator control) I have to get it from the underlying document like so:

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField3">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
       return viewEntry.getDocument().getItemValueString("City") + ", " +     viewEntry.getDocument().getItemValueString("State");
    }]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
```

But if I just tack on the City and State columns to my View design for the Domino View data source then the following code runs faster:

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField2">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
            return viewEntry.getColumnValue("City") + ", " + viewEntry.getColumnValue("State");
        }]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
```

And faster still is the EL equivalent:

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1"
        value="#{viewEntry.City}, #{viewEntry.State}">
</xp:text>
```

Since I address the View column in my XPages code by programmatic name and not by position, adding new columns to my View design as I need them doesn't seem to break anything (at least not yet ;)

Comment: Do not rely on UI views. There is no problem to add more columns (@paul mentioned order of columns, that definitely breaks classic `@DbLookups`). Main problem of user driven customization is with deleted columns or change in value formats.